# Infix to Postfix Conversion

Tags: c++-cli, infix-notation

I'm trying to code that converts infix expressions to postfix expressions. Currently, the program works correctly if I enter for e.g "5+6" it will output the correct answer which is "5 6 +". The problem occurs when I enter more than one operator for e.g "5+6-3", it outputs and incorrect answer "+3-". Can someone please point out where I'm making the error ? Thanks, in advance !

```
void main(){

Stack *s = new Stack;
string input;


cout <<"Enter Expression"<<endl;
cin>>input;

InfixToPostfix(input);

system("PAUSE");

}





string  InfixToPostfix(string input){

Stack *S = new Stack();

string postfix = "";
for (int i=0; i < input.length();i++){
    if (input[i]== ' '||input[i]==',') continue;
    else if (IsOperator(input[i]))
    {
        while(!S->IsStackEmpty() && S->StackTop() != '(' &&   HasHigherPrecedence(S->StackTop(),input[i]))
        {
            postfix=S->StackTop();
            S->Pop();
        }
        S->Push(input[i]);
    }
    else if(IsOperand(input[i]))
    {
        postfix +=input[i];
    }
    else if (input[i] == '(')
    {
        S->Push(input[i]);
    }
    else if (input[i]==')')
    {
        while(!S->IsStackEmpty() && S->StackTop() != '('){
            postfix += S->StackTop();
            S->Pop();
        }
        S->Pop();
    }
 }
while(!S->IsStackEmpty()){
    postfix +=S->StackTop();

    S->Pop();
}

cout <<""<<postfix;
return postfix;

 }

 bool IsOperand(char C)
 {

if(C>= '0' && C<= '9') return true;
if(C>= 'a' && C<= 'z') return true;
if(C>= 'A' && C<= 'Z') return true;
return false;
}

bool IsOperator(char C)
{
if(C=='+' || C== '-' || C =='*' || C == '/' ||C == '$')

{
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}


int IsRightAssociative(char op)

{
if(op=='$'){
    return true;
}else{

return false;
}
}
int GetOperatorWeight(char op){

int weight = -1;
switch(op)
{
case'+':
case '-':
weight=1;
break;
case '*':
case '/':
weight=2;
break;
case '$':
weight=3;
break;
}

return weight;
}

int HasHigherPrecedence ( char op1, char op2)

{

int op1Weight= GetOperatorWeight(op1);
int op2Weight = GetOperatorWeight(op2);


if(op1Weight == op2Weight)
{

    if(IsRightAssociative(op1))
{
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
    return op1Weight > op2Weight ? true:false;
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C++/CLI. It looks like regular C++ with an unknown `Stack` class...

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion: use a tree, rather than a stack, as an intermediate data structure. Let the operator with lowest precedence be the root of the tree and build it recursively from there. Then walk through the tree from left to right, again recursively, to generate the postfix version. That way, you can also keep track of the maximum stack depth for the postfix version, which can be important as many hand-held RPN calculators, for example, have very limited stack depths.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Yes I'm aware that it's easier to implement the RPN calculator using trees instead of stacks. But I already implemented the postfix using stacks so I was just planning to implement the infix also using stacks. Also, my grasp on how trees work isn't that great as yet, which is why I wanted to use stacks.